# PHP GET Function as NULL

Tags: php

I want to use GET in PHP and I know how to. The only problem is when I start my page I dont have a ?var=... on it. For example my site is

```
http://localhost/q/question.php
```

and in my code is

```
$num = $_GET['num'];
```

And I want to assume that if $num == NULL or has not been defined as in the link above.

I will generate a different page. because as example below just determines I am starting the questions in what ever page.

No num variable = Start Generating questions in array.

```
http://localhost/q/question.php?num=1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['num')){
header('Location: someotherpage.php');  //redirects user to someotherpage.php
//do something
}
else{
//do something else

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['num'))
   {
     echo "is not null";
   }
  else
  {
    echo "is null";
   }

?>
```